# Ubuntu grub boot problem

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I don't know exactly what is happening but I have some ideas.

Yesterday my ubuntu start crashing during the boot, sometimes the crash happens during the boot, and sometimes after I select the user and type the Password, the Ubuntu prompt me with the select User again and crash.

I have a dual-boot system with Ubuntu 20.04 and Windows 10.

I already tryied to load ubuntu on recovery mode and put that 'nomodeset' thing, but nothing change.

So I did a bootable Ubuntu Usb and runned on Try Ubuntu to try install and run ubuntu-repair

I got to the part that instruct me to put some commands on the cli, but the repair failled.

That is the Error Url

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/wPzxzPwCN9/

IDK more what to do.

Comment: You show Windows hibernated. Windows updates will turn fast start up back on which then sets hibernation flag. Grub will not boot hibernated Windows, nor Windows that needs chkdsk. Can you boot Windows directly from UEFI? Also grub is not updating as it creates grub.cfg.new with some sort of error. You have typo in some part of grub configuration files. Either /etc/default/grub or one of the scripts in /etc/grub.d. What did you edit? Boot Windows from UEFI menu, and turn off fast start up. Did Windows updates also update UEFI, which may revert settings to defaults and need to be changed again.

Comment: I didn't edited nothing. I now tryied to open GParted and realized that have a warning on /dev/sda2 Microsoft reserved partition, its normal?

Comment: I did that thing to fully shutdown windows and now the error that the boot-repair is giving me is the following "https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/xskXbm7wrR/"

Comment: Line 51: "Installation finished. No error reported." So grub installed in UEFI boot mode. The Microsoft reserved partition is required by Windows. It is unformatted so gparted typicality shows it as an error.